# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel' when excuting from azureml.core

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to execute the Azure ml sdk from the local system using the Jupyter notebook. When I run the below code i am getting an error.

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Datastore, Dataset

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add pip 20.1.1

Conda ruamel needs higher version of pip

```
conda install pip=20.1.1
```